# Django choose in what location images are loaded in model's save method

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's my save method for model with field `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)`:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            self.image = compress(self.image)
        if self.second_image:
            self.second_image = compress(self.second_image)
        if self.third_image:
            self.third_image = compress(self.third_image)
        if self.fourth_image:
            self.fourth_image = compress(self.fourth_image)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works fine and compresses all images but changes image's directory every time when I click save in django admin. It makes all images' paths be like:
before edited and saved: `products/2020/11/05/img.jpeg`
after:  `products/2020/11/05/products/2020/11/05/img.jpeg`
click save one more time: `products/2020/11/05/products/2020/11/05/products/2020/11/05/img.jpeg`
And then I get this error:

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /admin/shop/product/6/change/
Storage can not find an available filename for "products\2020\11\05\products\2020\11\05\products\2020\...... .jpeg".
Please make sure that the corresponding file field allows sufficient "max_length".
```

How can I fix this problem? I think I need to choose location where saved images would be stored. Django doesn't let me use absolute path in `upload_to` field so I have no idea.

compress func is:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files import File

def compress(image):
    im = Image.open(image)
    if im.mode != 'RGB':
        im = im.convert('RGB')
    im_io = BytesIO()
    im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
    compressed_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)
    return compressed_image
```

Comment: your model has 4 `ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)` ?

Comment: @cizario yes, second_image, third and fourth

Comment: try to add `null=True,` to each `ImageField(..)` and rerun migration commands and let see

Comment: @cizario didn't help, still creates recursed directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the filename is updated everytime. At each step, you should make sure that the filename is only a filename. Something like this:

```py
import os

if self.image:
    self.image = compress(self.image)
    self.image.name = os.path.basename(self.image.name)
```

I don't know exactly what is your compress function, but maybe you could also check that it doesn't do something weird with the filename.